# Python3 and Docker multistage build file not found

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I am noob to docker and i am trying to build a multistage dockerfile for python3

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as base
RUN apt-get -qy update && apt-get install python3 -y
WORKDIR /pydocktest
COPY test.py .

FROM  ubuntu:18.04 AS release
WORKDIR /pytest
COPY --from=base /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=base /pydocktest .
CMD ["./test.py"]
```

Then

```
docker build -t test .
docker run test
```

Output

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

but when i run `apt -get install python3` in the `release` part, it works perfect ? so why the need of multistage if i am going to reinstall python sorry if i sound dump

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: there is no need for a multistage if you reinstall Python in the final image.

Long answer: one reason for using a multistage is that you need special applications and files when building your application but don't need them at runtime. In your example, that's not the case.

As a suggestion also, you could use the python3 image instead of installing it yourself. That would simplify your Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
COPY test.py .
CMD [ "python", "./test.py" ]
```

If you want to learn more about the rationale behind multistage Dockerfiles, my [Learn Docker](https://mybook.to/docker) book explains them, and by the way it's a book written for noobs.